# Phase of a sine wave from a plot

Tags: trigonometry

How can I find the phase of a sine wave $y=A\cdot \sin(\omega_{n}t+\phi)$ from its plot?

[image]

Its phase is $\phi=89^{\circ}$ but how do I find it?

Comment: It's practically impossible to distinguish between $89^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: @Arthur I know but that is the given solution so I just mentioned that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phase is the distance that the *rising* zero-crossing is moved to the *left* of the $y$-axis.

In your example we can't see anything to the left of $x=0$, but instead we can find the *next* rising zero-crossing and subtract from $2\pi$.

In your graph it looks like there are rising zero-crossings at about $x=450$ and $x=1100$ (though it is hard to read them precisely on that graph). So a full wave of length $1100-450=650$ corresponds to $2\pi$ of phase and the phase offset of the curve is then given by
$$ 450\frac{2\pi}{1100-450} + \phi = 2\pi $$
or in other words
$$ \phi = 2\pi( 1-\frac{450}{1100-450} ) \approx 1.93 \approx 110^\circ $$

The fact that we don't get $89^\circ$ is due to errors in estimating the zero crossings at 450 and 1100. Using an actual ruler instead of just eyeballing as I did would improve precision.

If you want the phase in degrees, you can just use $360^\circ$ instead of $2\pi$ during the entire calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the phase by checking by how much degrees the 'original sine curve' is shifted to the right.
The original sine curve: $sin(\phi)$ is $0$ when $\phi$ is $0$
This one is $0$ at $89$ degrees, hence, that is the phase

Comment: I thought that it may be a more accurate way as every solution that I am given is very exact for example 89, 78, 88 degrees...

Comment: You can guess very near the answer at best. I cannot think of a way to reach the precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Concentrate just on your formula $f(t)=A\cdot \sin(\omega_{n}t+\phi)$. $A$ is the peak of the curve, so it is evident that $A=10 \cdot 10^{-5}$. Also, you can see from the graph that

$$f(0) = 10 \cdot {10^{ - 5}}\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\sin \left( \phi  \right) = 1\,\,\, \to \,\,\,\phi  = {\pi  \over 2}\,\,\,\,or\,\,\,\,\phi  = {90^ \circ }$$

${1^ \circ }$ error is due to some reading-error from the graph; however, it seems acceptable.

Comment: Actually, since the curve is near horizontal at the peaks, it can be difficult to see the horizontal position of the top of the peak precisely (especially if there is some noise in the signal). The position of the zero crossings can be read with greater precision -- and even if there's a DC offset one can find the zero as being halfway between the peaks anf throughs.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Here, in this picture, I think reading peaks is easier than reading zero-crossings! :) Anyway, you are the king! :D